# Kendo Timepicker: Save in different format than parseFormat

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, telerik, kendo-ui, timepicker

In our project our server expects time values to be a string in 24-hour format (HH:mm:ss). However we want to use kendo timepickers that display 12-hour format with AM/PM (hh:mm tt) to the end user. Right now I am using:

```
$('.timePicker').kendoTimePicker(
{  
      format: "hh:mm tt"
      parseFormats: ["HH:mm:ss"]
});
```

And this works fine in terms of displaying the correct value from the database. However the problem is that the value of the field is saving back out to 12-hour format (hh:mm tt) instead of 24(HH:mm:ss).

What can I do to display 12-hour format but save 24-hour?

Thank you

Comment: This is more on the parsing side. What do you see if you inspect: $(".timePicker").val()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your Controller , when you populate your Grid view . . Add this

```
Convert.ToDateTime(row. *Value of the Timepicker*).ToString("hh:mm tt")
```

Then on Saving, Add this on your controller

```
Convert.ToDateTime( *value of your Timepicker*).ToString("HH:mm:ss")
```